# Running node.js without automatic logs

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to run my node.js application without the automatic logs it prints in the terminal when answering a request (for example `127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 20 Jun 2012 09:55:49 GMT] "GET /url HTTP/1.1" 200 1559 "http://localhost:3020/url" ...`). Moreover I would like that my logs from `console.log()` still remain visible if possible.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm running express.js on top of Node.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a call to `app.use(express.logger())` (or something similar) in your code?

Comment: Yes, shouldn't I to see my logs through `console.log()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like brandon is saying I think you are using the [logger](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html) [middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) somewhere in your code. You should disable that part especially in [production mode](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration). Use something like this:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  var oneYear = 31557600000;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, by disabling that part I now don't see all the logs and just see my logs :-).

Comment: New name is morgan (https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan), e.g. you should search for a line like `app.use(morgan('dev'));`

Comment: Please update the answer with Boern's great contribution!